# Can we suggest a user to delete his/her own Question?

Tags: discussion

Question in case: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57116/12615

The user thinks there's a bug going on with `wp_enqueue_scripts`, but it was just a rogue line of code he later found and *commented* about.

Is there any intrinsic value in the question? Should we ask him to post the "solution" as an answer? Or this is valid case were we can suggest him to delete the Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain coding errors are *too localized*. You can suggest to delete or flag such a question.

Comment: Glad to know, thanks!